# Adding a form filter

Tags: forms, filter, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I'm currently working on a form in Microsoft Dynamics AX.
The form consists of a grid with about 10 fields from 4 different tables.
As the form is now it returns too many values so I need to include some sort of filter, it doesn't need to be dynamic, just a static filter saying only show the lines with value X in column Y.

Has anyone here got some experience with this sort of thing? Where do I start?

I must say I'm not experienced with Microsof AX at all, I've been working with it for about a month now.

I've tried to follow this guide: [How to: Add Filter Controls to a Simple List Form [AX 2012]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh745335.aspx)
But I got stuck at the second part (To add a control to the custom filter group) Step 2: I dont know which type of control to chose, and ik i pick lets say a ComboBox i cant get Step 3 to work because I dont see the 'Override Methods' they mention.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I usually do it this way:

- In ClassDeclaration, create as many QueryBuildRanges variables as fields to filter. Let's name them Criteria1, Criteria2, etc (name them properly, please, not as here)

  ```
  QueryBuildRange criteria1, criteria2;
  ```
- In each Datasource you need to filter, override method Init, an add code similar to this:

  ```
  super();
  criteria1 = this.query().datasource(tablenum(tableofdatasource)).addQueryRange(fieldNum(fieldtofilter))
  //criteria1.status(RangeStatus::locked); //optional - this way you can hide filter field to user, have it readonly for users, etc
  ```
- Create a control of type StringEdit or ListBox in form to be used as filter. Change their AutoDeclaration property to Yes. Override modified() method. In it, I use to put something similar to:

  ```
  super();
  element.changeFilters();
  ```
- In form, add method changeFilters();

  ```
  range rangeFromStringControl = StringEditControlName.text(); //Put in rangeFromStringControl the string to be used as filter, as a user would write it
  range rangeFromListBoxControl;
  criteria1.value(rangeFromStringControl);

  switch (listBoxControl.Selection())
  {
      case NoYesAll::All:
          rangeFromListBoxControl = ''; //Empty filter string - No filter at all
          break;
      case NoYesAll::No:
          rangeFromListBoxControl = QueryValue(NoYes::No); //Or whatever string filter value you want
          break;
      //Etc
  }

  //We have all filter strs done; let's filter for each main DataSource required with new filters
  DataSource1.executeQuery(); 
  //If there is other datasources joined to this one, it's usually no necessary to call their executeQuery;
  //If there are others with filters and not joined to it, call their executeQuery()
  ```
- If you need this filter to be applied when form is open, set appropiate initial values to controls, and then in form's run() method:

  ```
  run();
  element.changeFilters();
  ```